# Android webview open target="_blank" urls in popup window

Tags: java, android, webview

i am using webview in my android app.
i want to know is it possible to open target="_blank" urls on my webpage into android popup window??
or any other way to pop up links??

Comment: What do you mean by pop window? AlertDialogs ?

Comment: If You are looking to open up your url in AlertDialog which is so called pop window thn I have the code snippet which can help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//LAYOUT FILE webview_content.xml
```

```
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>

///CODE IN ACTIVITY
```

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

```
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.webview_content);





    WebView webView = (WebView) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             webView.loadUrl("YOUR URL");

       dialog.show();
```

Comment: Here I have created an xml layout for pop window/alert and the code in an activity which was placed in onButtonClick Listener to open the AlertDialog in my case. It will help you or this may be the perfect code what you were looking for. Thanks